# Can't work before_validation when nested field is delated with cocoon gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I have this migration and model for order and order_detail with cocoon gem.

```
class CreateOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :orders do |t|
      t.integer :total_price
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateOrderDetails < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :order_details do |t|
      t.integer :subtotal_price
      t.integer :unit_price
      t.integer :quantity
      t.references :order, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :order_details, inverse_of: :order, dependent: :destroy
  before_validation :calculate_order_price
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_details, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true

  def calculate_order_price
    order_details.each(&:calculate_order_detail_price)
    self.total_price = order_details.map(&:subtotal_price).sum
  end
end

class OrderDetail < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  def calculate_order_detail_price
    self.subtotal_price = unit_price * quantity
  end
end
```

When I save the record after to add or edit the nested field, it works well. But if I edit to delate nested field, calculate_order_price doesn't work.

If somebody knows about this, please advise me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option `:touch` which will make sure upon update the parent sets the `updated_at` (or other fields) but it will not run the validations. There is however also an option `:validate` (but not entirely sure it will be called upon destroy):

```
 belongs_to :order, validate: true
```

Otherwise, if those not work, you could do something like

```
class OrderDetail < ApplicationRecord 

  belongs_to :order 

  after_destroy :trigger_parent_validation

  def trigger_parent_validation 
    if order.present? 
      order.validate 
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: thanks your comment. I tried your ways, but doesn't work well.
When I delate nested field saved, it is going to be display:none. So when calculate_order_price run, it sums all of nested fields.

I want calculate_order_price to sum except display:none nested field.

Comment: You are confusing things: `display: none` is in the browser (we have to keep it, because rails needs to know which order-detail to delete, so we "hide" the element and set the `_destroy` flag). After posting the form to the controller, only _then_  the callbacks are run. If you need the number to update in the browser, you should be using the javascript callbacks `cocoon:after-insert` and `cocoon:after-destroy` which could also calculate the order price.

Comment: OK, I understand. I expected after_validation runs without nested-field destroyed. I'll try javascript `cocoon:after-remove`. Thank you helping me. I'm grad to contact with developer of cocoon gem.